# Cannot create some specific keyboard shortcuts (Shift + F4)

Tags: keyboard, mojave, shortcut

I want to reuse some common keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu. The first one is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (to open terminal), the second one is <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (to change input source). However, the  system preference seems to prevent me from using such special combinations. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Just reading between the lines, but I'm guessing by *"I want to reuse some common keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu."* what you mean is that your wanting to use these shortcuts in macOS?

Comment: @Monomeeth These shortcuts are very common in Ubuntu, and I want to use them in macOS. Sorry for the confusing wording.

Answer (score 1):

It will let you use Shift/F4*, assuming you have a service you can apply it to that will launch Terminal, but it won't let you use ctrl/shift without some further character.

*Also assuming you have Fkey set to **be** Fkeys & not 'convenience shortcuts' - set in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard, otherwise you'll have to add Fn.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked at that settings, will try it this afternoon.